# Dynamic column resizing in .Rprofile

Tags: r

I'd like to put the following in my .Rprofile:

```
# auto width adjustment
.adjustWidth <- function(...){
   options(width=Sys.getenv("COLUMNS"))
   TRUE
} 
.adjustWidthCallBack <- addTaskCallback(.adjustWidth)
```

This will dynamically resize the max columns in my R session to be the width of the window.  This works in an interactive session, but when doing something like R CMD INSTALL or a batch session I always get:

```
Error in options(width = Sys.getenv("COLUMNS")) : 
  invalid 'width' parameter, allowed 10...10000
Execution halted
```

How can I fix this? I assume the issue is that Sys.getenv("COLUMNS") is failing somehow? Is there some if() statement I could do that lets me detect if I run in batch or not? The original auto width adjustment code isn't mine, I found it somewhere else online.

Comment: There's also `interactive()`, which tests whether R is being used interactively or not; e.g., `if (interactive()) .adjustWidth <- function (...)` etc.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Maybe wrapping the option in a `try` function helps:

```
try( options(width=Sys.getenv("COLUMNS")), silent = TRUE)
```

Answer (score 1):

For me `COLUMNS` doesn't get updated when my X terminal window (vte based, on linux) gets resized while R is running, since it gets updated by bash after each command. (according to the accepted answer for [this question](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/61584/))

I found a hint towards a better solution on [this page](https://kb.iu.edu/d/abwh). It talks about a `resize` command for solaris, but also mentions `stty`, which linux does have.

So after reading the man-page (and some basic R questions), I came up with this:

```
# auto width adjustment
if(interactive()) {
    .adjustWidth <- function(...){
        options('width' = sapply(strsplit(system("stty size", intern = T), " "), "[[", 2))
        TRUE
    }
    .adjustWidthCallBack <- addTaskCallback(.adjustWidth)
}
```

Answer (score 1):

The interactive() check is VERY IMPORTANT: otherwise it doesn't work with update.packages()...

```
> update.packages(lib.loc="...",ask=FALSE,oldPkgs="httpuv")
trying URL 'http://cran.univ-lyon1.fr/src/contrib/httpuv_1.5.1.tar.gz'
...
stty: 'standard input': Inappropriate ioctl for device
Error in options(width = as.integer(howWide)) : 
  invalid 'width' parameter, allowed 10...10000
Calls: updatePrompt -> options
Execution halted
...
```