# Setting `width` in Rprofile

Tags: r, startup, rprofile

Relevant: [Dynamic column resizing in .Rprofile](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7725152/dynamic-column-resizing-in-rprofile)

If I attempt to pass `Sys.getenv("COLUMNS")` as an integer (or as numeric or as is, i.e., as a string) to the parameter `width` of `options()` in my user .Rprofile, I get an error upon startup:

```
Error in options(width = as.integer(Sys.getenv("COLUMNS"))): 
  invalid 'width' parameter, allowed 10...10000
```

However, if, once logged into an interactive session, I try the same manually, no error is thrown and `getOption("width")` returns a value identical to `as.integer(Sys.getenv("COLUMNS"))`.

I'd like to know why it doesn't work from my .Rprofile, especially since something similar appears in the examples given on the help page for *Startup*. I am using R in xterm and am on Linux (Arch).

Answer (score 3):

Maybe the `setwidth` package can help you: http://cran.r-project.org/web/packages/setwidth/index.html

It works for R running on interactive terminals on Linux (sounds like your case exactly).

You will just have to add `library(setwidth)` to your .Rprofile and it will change the width every time you resize the terminal.

Comment: This is great! Thanks very much. (I also use and enjoy the **colorout** package cited in the manual.) I'd still like to know why I can't seem to set `options(width = as.integer(Sys.getenv("COLUMNS")))` from my .Rprofile, as in the examples on `?Startup`.

Comment: colorout is great too and I am using it. I suspect that upon startup the COLUMNS is not yet set. Maybe you can try to write something like `currentValue <- Sys.getenv("COLUMNS")` in your .Rprofile and see what you get?

Comment: You're right: during start-up `Sys.getenv("COLUMNS")` is `""`, which I don't understand, since the shell variable `COLUMNS` is set, i.e., `printf '%s\n' $COLUMNS` returns a value prior to initiating R in the same shell session.

Comment: I am not really sure what might be going on with R startup. But maybe it's possible that R is spawning it's own terminal before starting. You can also try running that `printf` from within .Rprofile maybe and see if it is set there. If not - you will probably have to seek another way that does not rely on $COLUMNS initially.

Comment: This solution is superced by base R. You can find a nice solution by Dean Scarff [here](https://scarff.id.au/blog/2021/updating-r-output-width-after-resizing-the-terminal-startup/).